# count number of occurences in linux directory based on date value

Tags: linux, csv, count, wc

So I have quite a bit of files that I want to to check the file count of based on date, but the thing is dates overlap in the files sometimes. For example a file could look like this

| issue_date | cert_id | serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-14 06:00:00 | 123 | abca234 |
| 2023-05-14 23:59:00 | 456 | qascmal |
| 2023-05-15 00:00:00 | 789 | acmaal |
| 2023-05-16 12:10:00 | 1231 | acmkla |

In the directory I have a bunch of files that may have two dates or more in the name so there is no way of knowing how many certs belong to each date. For example
2023-05-15-2023-05-18.csv.gmz, 2023-05-18-2023-05-19-2023.csv.gmz, etc.
Is there a quick and easy way to count these files based on the issue date above, obviously issue_date isn't unique but serial number/cert_id is. so I could use that in conjunction.
What I'm trying to do is programmatically check counts based on a given date, but I'm not sure querying these files may be too efficient, and maybe it's best using an API on the source of where these files are coming from. But thought I would ask.

So the solution if I typed in 2023-05-14 as the given date I would get two entries, and for the 15th I would get 1 entry and 16th 1 as well.

IMPORTANT UPDATE : I forget sometimes certs at the end of one file will carry over into the beginning of the next, so I will have to account for duplicates. Right now I have this
`zgrep -c -F '2023-05-11' *2023-05-11*.gz | awk -F: '{n+=$2} END {print n}'` but doesn't account for that fact.

Comment: `grep -l 'date' *.csv | wc -l`

Comment: I'm searching these files but not getting close to the number expected.. and I think it's because of the -l command. It looks like this refers to the list of file names, but I want to count each file in the present directory grouped by date.

Comment: ```grep -c 'date' *.csv``` this looks like it could work

Comment: dang but it looks like it will only work on a file unzipped, .gz seems to throw a wrench in things.

Comment: *"sometimes certs at the end of one file will carry over .. to the next"*. Yikes. As you say you have an API to retrieve this information, you're better off spending your time getting that to work. (IMHO). Good luck!

Comment: yeah I will have to get some access to it, but was wondering if there was a quicker way to get it done, but doesn't seem like it would be very efficient :D ```zgrep '2023-05-11*' *2023-05-11*.gz | cut -d, -f3,5 | sort -u | wc -l``` tried this but I don't think it worked haha

Comment: I thought you wanted to count the number of files with matches, not the number of individual matches. The question says **Is there a quick and easy way to count these files based on the issue date above**

Comment: What do you mean by certs carrying over? Do do you mean the line is split between files?

Comment: sorry I forgot to check this, I want to count the number of records in the files where a specific date is mentioned in that date column. What I mean by carrying over is having the same record in one file at the end and present at the beginning in another, in other words the records aren't always unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this to solve the overlap, I created a bash script that could solve this problem.

```
# Create an array to store the distinct IDs
declare -A distinct_ids

# Record the start time
start_time=$(date +%s)

# Loop through all the compressed archive files in the current directory
for file in ./*.gz; do
    # Extract the appropriate column (serial number) from the CSV file and append to a temporary file
    zcat "$file" | awk -F',' '{print $4}' >> extracted_ids.txt
done

# Sort and count the unique IDs using sort and uniq
sort extracted_ids.txt | uniq > unique_ids.txt

# Count the number of distinct unique IDs
num_unique_ids=$(wc -l < unique_ids.txt)

# Record the end time
end_time=$(date +%s)

# Calculate the time taken
duration=$((end_time - start_time))

# Display the result
echo "Number of distinct unique IDs: $num_unique_ids"
echo "Time taken: $duration seconds"

# Clean up temporary files
rm extracted_ids.txt unique_ids.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate all the uncompressed files and then pipe that to `grep`:

```
zcat *2023-05-11*.gz | grep -c -F 2023-05-11
```